# how can I see what ports mongo is listening on from mongo shell?

Tags: mongodb

If I have a mongo instance running, how can I check what port numbers it is listening on from the shell? I thought that `db.serverStatus()` would do it but I don't see it. I see this

```
"connections" : {
    "current" : 3,
    "available" : 816
```

Which is close... but no. Suggestions? I've read the docs and can't seem to find any command that will do this.

Comment: Do you need mongo shell? Or regular unix shell will do? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I'm specifically wondering if this is possible inside of mongo shell -- since I already found info which is close.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

From the system shell you can use `lsof` (see Derick's answer below) or `netstat -an` to view what a process is actually doing.  However, assuming you only have access to the `mongo` shell (which your question title implies), then you can run the [`serverCmdLineOpts()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) command.  That output will give you all the arguments passed on the command line (argv) and the ones from the config file (parsed) and you can infer the ports `mongod` is listening based on that information.  Here's an example:

```
db.serverCmdLineOpts()
{
    "argv" : [
        "./mongod",
        "-replSet",
        "test",
        "--rest",
        "--dbpath",
        "/data/test/r1",
        "--port",
        "30001"
    ],
    "parsed" : {
        "dbpath" : "/data/test/r1",
        "port" : 30001,
        "replSet" : "test",
        "rest" : true
    },
    "ok" : 1
}
```

If you have not passed specific port options like the ones above, then the `mongod` will be listening on 27017 and 28017 ([http console](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/#http-status-interface)) by default.  Note: there are a couple of other arguments that can alter ports without being explicit, see here:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#sharding.clusterRole

Comment: My result is: `{ "argv" : [ "mongod" ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }` that doesn't tell me much. I guess it's telling me I'm on the default port.

Comment: right - if it's not specified at all (and in your case that seems like it) then everything is defaults, which puts you on 27017

Answer (score 243):

You can do this from the Operating System shell by running:

```
sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN | grep mongo
```

Comment: @SmartyTwiti I explicitly asked for a command using the mongo shell; lsof doesn't work

Comment: For anybody reading the above comment, it might be because you must run `lsof` with `sudo` to see `mongodb` listed

Answer (score 45):

Try this:

```
db.runCommand({whatsmyuri : 1})
```

It will display both the IP address and the port number.

Comment: is that new? what version of mongo did it show up in?

Comment: @jcollum Version 3.0 has this new feature.

Comment: This seems shows shell's port or something...
Output from `lsof` :
>mongod  14942 dmitrii    5u  IPv4 0xc36ad5231f84011d      0t0  TCP *:27017 (LISTEN)
And from `whatsmyurl` command:
{ "you" : "127.0.0.1:50294", "ok" : 1 }

And they not match.

Comment: this one worked for me, running mongo on a docker container.

Answer (score 13):

MongoDB only listens on one port by default (27017). If the `--rest` interface is active, port 28017 (27017+1000) will also be open handling web requests for details.

MongoDB supports a `getParameter` command, but that only works if you're already connected to the Database (at which point you already know the port).

Comment: Hmm, so we can say that if I'm connected and don't know the port, it must be 27017. If the port is not 27017, I must know the port in order to connect. Sound right?

Answer (score 4):

You can try, from the mongo shell:

- db.getMongo()

> Use this command to test that the mongo shell has a connection to the
> proper database instance.

```
connection to <IP>:<PORT>
```

- db.collection.explain()

> For unsharded collections, explain returns the following serverInfo
> information for the MongoDB instance:

```
"serverInfo" : {
   "host" : <string>,
   "port" : <int>,
   "version" : <string>,
   "gitVersion" : <string>
}
```

[Default MongoDB Port](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/default-mongodb-port/index.html)