# How to check the current configuration of MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, configuration

I've found documentation for the different [configuration options](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/administration/configuration/), but how can I check which options are being used on a live system?

Is there a way to see which options were set, or at minimum which configuration file is being used?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Found the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9361047/947305

There's a [getCmdLineOpts](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/) command in the mongo shell. Run the following:

```
db._adminCommand( {getCmdLineOpts: 1})
```

Comment: I get the response `{ "argv" : [ "mongod" ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }`

Comment: It does print both `argv` of the process and also the parsed config file. (tested on MongoDB 4.4.8)

Comment: From mongodb documentation: "The document in the parsed field includes all runtime options, including those parsed from the command line and those specified in the configuration file, if specified." https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/

Answer (score 38):

to get live settings, you can use

`db.adminCommand({getParameter:"*"})`

> previously called _adminCommand with underscore in front, so if you
> have old mongo running, try that one.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getParameter/

Comment: Thank you! It seems like it's now called `db.adminCommand` (without underscore).
Can't edit the answer to change it.

Answer (score 0):

To know the current **configuration file**, you can try:

```
cat(db._adminCommand({getCmdLineOpts: 1}).parsed.config);
```

> The method returns with output relative to the current shell session
> and does not impact the server.