# Print runtime mongo configuration via mongo cli

Tags: mongodb

Was looking at this: [How to check the current configuration of MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22695367/how-to-check-the-current-configuration-of-mongodb)

Tried it below:

> use admin
>       switched to db admin
>   db.runCommand( { getCmdLineOpts: 1 } )
>       { "argv" : [ "mongod" ], "parsed" : { }, "ok" : 1 }

My `/etc/mongod.conf` file:

```
user@mongo:/# cat /etc/mongod.conf
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1
   port: 27017
```

Something I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

It is very likely that your `mongod` process is not running with the configuration file `/etc/mongod.conf` specified. If you are, you should be seeing the configuration file in the output of [getCmdLineOpts()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/). For example:

```
{
   "argv" : [
      "/usr/bin/mongod",
      "--config",
      "/etc/mongod.conf"
   ],
   "parsed" : {
      "config" : "/etc/mongod.conf"
   }
}
```

For more information see [getCmdLineOpts command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/getCmdLineOpts/#getcmdlineopts)